# SimpleXML: Read an .xml file without having to give the full name of the file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have the following code

```
   $url ='pathfile/';
   $file = glob($url . '.xml');
   xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Can't connect to URL");
```

So what i am trying to achieve here, is to read with simpleXML an .xml file. I do not want to have an absolute path, because i change the xml every day and the name is always different. 
So, how can i get the .xml file without having to give the files' name?

Best regards

Comment: [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) returns an _array_ of files matching your patter, so `$file` is an array of filenames... you need to get the value(s) from that array, which are the individual filenames, not try to load a file called `Array`

Answer (score 0):

`glob()` should allow you to use an asterisk as a wildcard, so for your purposes something like the following:

```
$url ='pathfile/';
$file = glob($url . '*.xml');
```

This is with the assumption that you replace the XML in the directory, rather than add it next to the older ones. As an additional note, glob() returns an array of matched files, so you'll want to loop through the $file variable above.

Comment: I tried it both ways, with asterisk and without and as i print_r the $file variable i got an empty array, although my path is 100% correct.

Comment: What's the actual path to the file and what does the code you're using to try and fetch it look like? It's possible there's a typo or a mix-up between absolute/relative paths.